# Enumerate properties on an object

Tags: typescript, iterator

Given the following class, how can I enumerate its properties, i.e. get an output like `[station1, station2, station3 ...]`?

I can only see how to enumerate the values of the properties, i.e. `[null, null, null]`.

```
class stationGuide {
    station1: any;
    station2: any;
    station3: any;

    constructor(){
        this.station1 = null;
        this.station2 = null;
        this.station3 = null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You have two options, using the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or use [for/in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
class stationGuide {
    station1: any;
    station2: any;
    station3: any;

    constructor(){
        this.station1 = null;
        this.station2 = null;
        this.station3 = null;
     }
}

let a = new stationGuide();
Object.keys(a).forEach(key => console.log(key));

for (let key in a) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20stationGuide%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20station1%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20station2%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20station3%3A%20any%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.station1%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.station2%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.station3%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20stationGuide()%3B%0AObject.keys(a).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20console.log(key))%3B%0A%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20a)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(key)%3B%0A%7D))

Comment: If you want to access the value then you can refer it as 
`console.log( a[key] )`

Comment: Related: [Use Object.values with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42966362/1497596)

Comment: Are there any advantages / disadvantages between the two options?

Comment: @MortimerCat I haven't checked the benchmarks so I can't say for sure, but not that I'm aware of.  It usually depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "Do they produce the exact same result for all cases" or are there any nuances? (e.g. One method might skip inherited properties).

Comment: @MortimerCat Well, the `Object.keys` approach will only list direct properties of the object and not inherited ones. But the `for/in` will also iterate over inherited properties.

Answer (score 18):

With the [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) object you are able to to access and modify any object programmatically. This approach also doesn't throw a "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'" error.

```
class Cat {
  name: string
  age: number

  constructor(name: string, age: number){
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
   }
}

function printObject(obj: any):void{
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  const values = keys.map(key => `${key}: ${Reflect.get(obj,key)}`)
  console.log(values)
}

const cat = new Cat("Fluffy", 5)
const dog = {
  name: "Charlie",
  age: 12,
  weight: 20
}

printObject(cat)
printObject(dog)
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBdoG8BQ0PQHZgLYFMAuaCBAJwEssBzdTMao7AV1wCN8zU6NgB7LKTLNgCPmQAUOAsSFVqAGmgMmWVhzIBKNJl3QEACwoQAdNPzQAvNjz4eew8ZMqryxvegBfVN9QAzZixRCgFoAAdKLAQAeTYAK3xRCT544jAsAE9NQgA3PgoAEx1MfkEkAGt8DJhrWITRE0rq5PjNe1LSaBywEGZ8Gugm01wwMIkmqwA+aAADABJkJs9iBYAlfD8QRIQTRgQWuIUmzU8Ztt0Ovi2TED5qCW7e-rbfDqRgRFcsfAB3OEQJAAiABivT8fgygKUAFY2m9oAU7q5ihhzMRAbADGAyCAKPgofYVMQAIwAJgU9h++Ao1AMCGIpIADD5uBEqDF4tsJB8EG02VE6lzEdRNEA))

Comment: Is it better to go for `Reflect.get(obj, key)` or `(obj as any)[key]`? Is there any benefit?

Comment: in this case it is better to go for `Reflect.get(obj, key)`, because `Object.keys(obj)` returns an `any[]` and `Reflect.get(obj, key)` doesn't require the key to be a string.

e.g.: `dog[Object.keys(dog)[0]]` will produce the following error: 

_Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; age: number; weight: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; age: number; weight: number; }'_