# How to use Object.values with typescript?

Tags: typescript, object

I am trying to form a  comma separated string from an object,

```
const data = {"Ticket-1.pdf":"8e6e8255-a6e9-4626-9606-4cd255055f71.pdf","Ticket-2.pdf":"106c3613-d976-4331-ab0c-d581576e7ca1.pdf"};
const values = Object.values(data).map(x => x.substr(0, x.length - 4));
const commaJoinedValues = values.join(',');
console.log(commaJoinedValues);
```

How to do this with TypeScript?

getting an error file:

```
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.'
at: '216,27'
source: 'ts'
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

using Object.keys instead.

```
const data = {
  a: "first",
  b: "second",
};

const values = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);

const commaJoinedValues = values.join(",");
console.log(commaJoinedValues);
```

Comment: Note that this an alternative (a good one!), not an actual answer on how to use ES7's `Object.values` in TS to solve the OP's compile error. To do that you simply need `ES2017` in your `--lib` setting.

Comment: @Aaron your solution is so complex that anyone new to typescript can't accepted,to compile you must add `ES2017` lib, and must include polyfills library where use it.give different answer against different people is king.

Comment: @holi-jave It's not "my solution" its just how TS and non-yet-standard JS features work, like the OP's attempted use of `ES7/Object.values()`. Maybe you think its complex (I don't disagree), but that's just the nature of trying to use future features like `Object.values()` today. Its always been this way. Even `Object.keys()` should still be polyfilled if you were targeting ES3 or want to support IE8 (hopefully you don't anymore!) It's a good idea in general to understand ES features, browser support, and polyfilling if you are in web development!

Comment: @Aaron I'm not said it is complex,but for someone new to typescript/javascript is more complex and don't accepted.

Comment: @Aaron if you only emphasize polyfills you needn't add lib `ES2017`,usually polyfills library provide its own typeings.

Comment: @holi-jave Nope. If you only add polyfill TS will still give the compile error the OP showed us. You need `--lib` for TS to understand what level of ES features you support. You need polyfills for it to actually work in the browser. So understanding *both* is important. Maybe my explanation is not clear enough.

Comment: @Aaron let's you add `core-js` polyfill,the typescript will find typings in `core-js` package.json if not exists,then the compiler will find typings in `@types/core-js`,I said right?so you needn't add `es2017` lib,because in `es2017` have many features that polyfill not implemented yet.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not good at english,so I wish you to understand I said.for the typescript compiler mechanisim you could to see [module-resolution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: @holi-jave No, `core-js` does [not have type defs for ES7 features](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/core-js/index.d.ts#L291). You need to use `lib: es2017` for those. There may be other type defs out there for ES2017 but you'd still need to install them and you shouldn't use them, use the built-in type defs for ES libs.

Comment: @Aaron because they provide types in `@types/core-js`,many popular library provide its types into to @types

Comment: `@types/core-js` does not have a definition for `Object.values()`. That's why you need `lib: ES2017`. Try it!

Comment: @Aaron yes,you are right,that `@types/core-js` only support its own declarations not include `Object.values` because if incldues `Object.values` declaration it will reports many duplicate identifiers error.

Comment: @Aaron after search I found `core-js` has defined its own Object type not inherit typescript `ES2017` at line 496 in `@types/core-js` that you could see.

Comment: @Aaron we are wrong,in `@types/core-js` it indicate that was using `es6.symbol` so we need only add lib 'es6'/'es6.symbol'.I said right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, core-js uses `["es2017", "dom", "dom.iterable"]`.

Comment: @Aaron I have talk about something with another answer that you can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138954/discussion-between-holi-java-and-aaron).

Comment: This does not work (did it ever?) because `Object.keys` returns a string array which [cannot be used to index the data object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGCBcMARAGYCWATtEQDQ4wBGhREApqGHLVgL4DcWLB2gwAbggA2AV1YQ0MAPIMAVuygA6ANasAnhAAUiZAEp1AWwQAHfdp1oAfPCQIA2rYC6xgUPAjQZiwApEDIwVjgANUkZOXRxaVl1ZRCwfVoiLx9IEAlWdQkQAHN9fyCU8KiEiEysIA).

Comment: @lawrence-witt exactly, it does not work now, this is my work around:     `const dataAny: any = data; return dataAny[key];`

Comment: This is terrible that there isn't a way to get the values directly.

Answer (score 258):

`Object.values()` is [part of ES2017](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-object.values), and the compile error you are getting is because you need to configure TS to use the ES2017 library. You are probably using ES6 or ES5 library in your current TS configuration.

Solution: use `es2017` or `es2017.object` in your [`--lib` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

For example, using `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
}
```

Note that targeting ES2017 with TypeScript *does **not** emit polyfills in the browser for ES2017* (meaning the above solves your *compile* error, but you can still encounter a *runtime* error because the browser doesn't implement ES2017 `Object.values`), it's up to you to polyfill your project code yourself if you want. And since [`Object.values` is not yet well supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) (at the time of this writing) you definitely want a polyfill: [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) will [do the job](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2.4.1/modules/es7.object.values.js).

Comment: @ErikvanVelzen You edited the answer to change the case of `ES2017` to `es2017` but AFAIK this is not necassary, but I always want to learn, was there a reason for the change?

Comment: ^ To answer my own question: `ES2017`, `DOM` (uppercase) is listed in the `tsc --init` comment as the valid values and it works correctly in the compiler, but the [JSON schema](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/tsconfig.json) only enumerates the `es2017`, `dom` (lowercase) options, so JSON IDE/linter will flag `ES2017`, `DOM` as an invalid values (even though they are valid). A bit confusing.

Comment: Indeed that was the reason. It does work uppercase as you note. `tsc --help` displays lowercase though

Comment: Isn't the core-js is included in angular, if not that how to add this pollyfill?

Comment: You say that I need to include core-js, but https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html says "List of library files to be included in the compilation.". Edit: just tried and no, they don't add it. The docs are a bit miss-leading.

Comment: @Totty.js The library files that TS includes are for *type-checking only*, in other words it doesn't actually emit any JS library polyfills for things like `Object.values()`. In other words you can get around the compile error but still run into runtime errors if you run in a browser that doesn't have `Object.values()`.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks I got it. Anyway the docs are not very clear, I guess they need to be very clear because is a big thing

Comment: Also if I want to use Object.values, I need to use "import "core-js/es7";", but in tsconfig.lib I need to add "es2017". Why I can't add es7? I get this error: "Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: @Totty.js ES7 isn't an official version. ES6 was renamed to ES2015, and some people (including myself) referred to ES features beyond ES6 as ES7 but the correct versions after ES6/ES2015 are ES2016, ES2017, ES2018, etc.

Comment: @Aaron but why then core-js doesn't have es2017? They are not consistent with each other, right?

Comment: @Totty.js CoreJS and TypeScript are different projects, they just named things differently. TS did it the "right" way. Actually, looks like the most recent version of CoreJS has changed/corrected their naming. You can just include `core-js` or specific features like `core-js/features/object/values`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just thought there was a "standard"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178159/discussion-between-aaron-and-totty-js).

Comment: you the real mvp

Comment: This seems to be not enough for TS v. <= 3.8.3?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwHIBDfAH3wCN8Aac9dAGwkIDsoSpmBXAW3IkwB8AbgCwAKEbAohKAC5YoseIzMAzlIjNgmAJYRVCKAHlyAKzTAAdAGsIIVQApCASkUr1UAG6F6BxCfNUK296Tn0nV3EgA

Answer (score 20):

You can use `Object.values` in TypeScript by doing this `(<any>Object).values(data)` if for some reason you can't update to ES7 in tsconfig.

Comment: @Aaron at the time of the posting there were comments indicating people using a specific version of Angular had issues updating the lib where it wasn't working.  Which is why I put `if for some reason you can't update to ES7 in tsconfig`

Answer (score 13):

Instead of

```
Object.values(myObject);
```

use

```
Object["values"](myObject);
```

In your example case:

```
const values = Object["values"](data).map(x => x.substr(0, x.length - 4));
```

This will hide the ts compiler error.

Comment: you are genius(^-' )b

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ObjectConstructor' has no index signature.ts(7017)

Comment: This is a mis-use of TS. You should configure the compiler with the `lib` setting to reflect how you're using it, not intentionally escape the compiler.

Comment: @AaronBeall it's a good use if for some reason you cant upgrade to es2017

Comment: @Dino You don't need to upgrade to es2017, you can use [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) to polyfill all the way down to ES5. TypeScript has no runtime, the `lib` setting is just to get the correct type-checking.

Comment: @Dino if you can't upgrade to es2017 why are you using a function that is defined in es2017?

Answer (score 13):

I have increased target in my `tsconfig.json` to enable this feature in TypeScript

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the target is not a solution in case you want to keep compatibility with older browsers. Typescript has to be able to transpile an ES2017 syntax to ES2015.

Answer (score 4):

I just hit this exact issue with Angular 6 using the CLI and workspaces to create a library using `ng g library foo`.

In my case the issue was in the `tsconfig.lib.json` in the library folder which did not have `es2017` included in the `lib` section.

Anyone stumbling across this issue with Angular 6 you just need to ensure that you update you `tsconfig.lib.json` as well as your application `tsconfig.json`

Comment: i've put es2017 in both tsconfig.lib and tsconfig.json, but still i get the error 'entries doesn't exist on Object' error when trying to use entries. Is there anything else i should change/update?

Comment: i changed the target in tsconfig.lib to es2017 just now, still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Having my `tslint` rules configuration here always replacing the line `Object["values"](myObject)` with `Object.values(myObject)`.

Two options if you have same issue:

`(Object as any).values(myObject)`

or

```
/*tslint:disable:no-string-literal*/
`Object["values"](myObject)`
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `Object["values"]`?

Answer (score -7):

Simplest way is to cast the `Object` to `any`, like this:

```
const data = {"Ticket-1.pdf":"8e6e8255-a6e9-4626-9606-4cd255055f71.pdf","Ticket-2.pdf":"106c3613-d976-4331-ab0c-d581576e7ca1.pdf"};
const obj = <any>Object;
const values = obj.values(data).map(x => x.substr(0, x.length - 4));
const commaJoinedValues = values.join(',');
console.log(commaJoinedValues);
```

And voila – no compilation errors ;)

Answer (score -7):

Even simpler, use `_.values` from underscore.js
https://underscorejs.org/#values