# JavaScript/ES 6: Compare arrays length in an Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an Object containing multiple arrays like this

```
someObj = {
    array1:['a', 'b'],
    array2:['a', 'b', 'c'],
    array3:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
```

Is there any built-in method or property in JS/ES6 which returns the largest array or length of the largest array? Please suggest

Comment: For that, you have iterate each value, and compare the length of arrays.

Comment: `Math.max(...Object.values(someObj).map(arr => arr.length))`

Comment: @Bergi Using `Object.values` would not be safer as IE is not supporting it. We could use `maps` instead.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Who cares about IE? Install a polyfill, or - more importantly - use a transpiler for the spread syntax. Notice that OP asked for ES6, he's probably fine with ES8 as well.

Comment: @bergi Always nice to hear comments like this. All serious JS development these days use transpilers. There is _no_ need to write ES5 anymore these days. It is like writing assembly language. Oh wait, ES5 is the assembly language of the web. Not meant to be written my humans. It is a transpiler target. Or should be.

Comment: @RayToal I think lots of serious JS development runs modern code natively without any transpilers. You need them only if you need to support older environments. Btw, I'm from the old school and still prefer to hand-assemble my ES5 code :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm using Typescript and I'm getting error - Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Comment: @pupil https://stackoverflow.com/q/42966362/1048572

Comment: There's also the old "hey we are using this code within a private intranet where everyone has a modern up-to-date browser that natively runs ES2017+". But yes, for JS in the wild, it's gotta be ES5 (whether native or transpiled). Though writing code without spreads, destructuring, interpolation, promises, etc. is just.... *shudder*  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a for loop and iterate through it comparing the length of the arrays.

```js
var someObj = {
  array1: ['a', 'b'],
  array2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  array3: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}

var max = 0;
for (x in someObj) {
  someObj[x].length > max ? max = someObj[x].length : max;
}

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and check the value of accumulator with the array length.

Use `Object.values()` to get all the values of the array.

```js
var someObj = {
    array1:['a', 'b'],
    array2:['a', 'b', 'c'],
    array3:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    array4:['a', 'b', 'c']
}

var maxLength = Object.values(someObj).reduce((a,e) => { return a > e.length ? a:e.length}, 0);

console.log(maxLength);
```

Comment: `(a, e) => Math.max(a, e.length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to get all of the values for any object. Here's a neat oneshot which will return the longest list in combination with `reduce`:

```
const longestList = Object.values(someObj)
  .reduce((longest, list) => list.length > longest.length ? list : longest)
```

- Object.values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values
- reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce