# Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' Typescript when using Object.values(map)

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, javascript-objects

I want to iterate through my key/value pairs and push all the values for each key into its own array. These arrays of values of each key should be pushed to a single output array.

I hope this explains what I'm trying to do:

```
Input: map = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]}

Output:  output = [["hello","hey","howdy"],["Goodbye","Ciao"]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
return Object.values(map)
```

Any help on why I'm getting the error in TypeScript. In Javscript it seemed to compile and return the correct answer.

```
 Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'
```

For background, this is part of a grouping anagrams problem so I'm populating my Map as follows from a provided array "str" of strings.

```
 let map = {};
  str.forEach(anagram => {
    const sortedWord = anagram
      .split("")
      .sort()
      .join("");
    map[sortedWord] = map[sortedWord] || [];
    map[sortedWord].push(anagram);
  });
  return Object.values(map)
}
```

Comment: Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967397/2887218) is the "right" answer  to your question, even though it's not the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `values` the code can operate with `keys`. From the documentation:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

Please read further here: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

As a solution I would consider the following in your case:

```js
(function() {
  const input = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]};
  
  console.log('input', input);
  
  const output = Object.keys(input).map(key => input[key]);
  
  console.log('output', output);
})();
```

I guess this alternative works like charm.