# Prevent jest from interfering with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

How can I use jest and typescript while targeting es5? My installation of jest seems to be causing typescript to erroneously think some object methods exist when they do not.

**Summary** Before installing jest, `npx tsc ./index.ts --target es5` throws an error because `Object.values` does not exist in es5, exactly as I would expect. After installing jest, the same command no longer throws errors. Note: I am **not** asking how to use Object.values, I am asing why typescript is letting me when it should not.

A minimal example follows.

#### The Setup

Directory:

```
node_modules/
index.js
index.ts
package.json
package-lock.json
```

and

```js
// package.json
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.4.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}

// index.ts
export const f = (x: Object) => Object.values(x);
```

I would expect typescript to throw an error when compiling because `Object.values` is not available in `es5`. And this occurs:

```
> npx tsc ./index.ts --target es5
```

yields:

```
index.ts:1:40 - error TS2339: Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

1 export const f = (x: Object) => Object.values(x);
                                         ~~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

#### The problem

After installing jest (`npm install jest --save-dev`), the same typescript command runs without complaint:

```
# after installing jest
> npx tsc ./index.ts --target es5
```

no errors.

How can I use jest together with typescript, and get accurate warnings about `Object.values`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jest with typescript and target es5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491474/using-jest-with-typescript-and-target-es5)

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is also my question, and basically the same as this. SO linked that question to a different one, and told me "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." ... so I opned a new question (after the linking). I did not actually realize anyone could see that question. I'm a bit confused about the linking. (Edit: I have since deleted that question.)

Comment: And to be clear, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966362/how-to-use-object-values-with-typescript definitely does not answer this question. That one is about how to use object.values, this one is about jest causing errors to incorrectly disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target` means that syntactic features are transpiled to specified target, it does not imply that polyfillable features cannot be used, although it defaults to ES5 types for `es5` target without `lib` configuration option:

> Note: If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are injected. The default libraries injected are:
>
> ► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>
> ► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

Since Jest is supposed to run in Node environment, `jest` package includes `@types/node` which enables the use of ES6+ libraries.

The solution is to not rely on default TypeScript configuration and specify all relevant options explicitly. There should be separate TypeScript configurations for production and tests. In order for TypeScript to not pick automatically `@types` typings that may not belong to current environment, `types` option needs to be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1):

This setup works for me:

Add types info:

```
npm i @types/jest @types/node
```

Add jest and typescript support:

```
npm i -D jest ts-jest typescript
```

Generate default jest config:

```
jest --init
```

Set jest.config.js config tranfomrm option like this:

```
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
```

Add test proc to be tested (sum.ts):

```
export default function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b
}
```

Add test (sum.test.ts):

```
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})
```

Modify package.json "scripts" option like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest",
}
```

run
`npm run test`

Comment: I just tried this; `npx tsc ./index.ts --target es5` still does not respect `--target es5`. E.g., using Object.values or Object.entries should throw typescript errors, but it does not.