# Types for a function that receives an object of type `[key: string]: SOME_TYPE` and returns an array of type `SOME_TYPE[]`

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, object, typescript-typings

I have some objects containing DB documents that I constantly need to convert to arrays.

Example:

```
const MY_OBJECT = {
  docId_1: {...doc1},
  docId_2: {...doc2},
  docId_3: {...doc3},
  // AND SO ON
}
```

I need to convert it to an array like this:

```
const MY_ARRAY_FROM_OBJECT = [
  {...doc1}, 
  {...doc2}, 
  {...doc3},
  // AND SO ON...
]
```

And this is code I use to do the conversion:

```
function buildArrayFromObject(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const arr = [];
  for (const key of keys) {
    arr.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

And I need to type that function so I can use it with objects that has types like these:

```
interface BLOGPOSTS_ALL {
  [key: string]: BLOGPOST
}

interface PRODUCTS_ALL {
  [key: string]: PRODUCT
}
```

So when I call them with each different object, I want Typescript to know what the return array type will be.

For example:

```
const BLOGPOSTS_ALL_ARRAY = buildArrayFromObject(BLOGPOSTS_ALL);  // SHOULD BE "BLOGPOST[]"
const PRODUCTS_ALL_ARRAY = buildArrayFromObject(PRODUCTS_ALL);    // SHOULD BE "PRODUCT[]"
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
function buildArrayFromObject<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T): T[K][] {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const arr = [];
  for (const key of keys) {
    arr.push(obj[key]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

And the returning type of the function is being evaluated by Typescript as type `never[]`

Comment: First of all, is there something limiting you to use the function `Object.values(..)`?

Comment: @r3dst0rm No problem. I can use that. I'm just used to `Object.keys()`

Comment: Actually, `Object.values()` is not supported by IE, so I'd rather go with `Object.keys()`

Comment: As noted in another comment, you can cast the return value of Object.keys to the following: `const keys = Object.keys(obj) as K[];` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is the following:

Create an abstraction type to define what your database handles look like:

```js
// Create an Entity type to define how your database objects look like
type Entities<T> = { [key: string]: T | undefined }
```

Therefore you can express your products and blogposts like this:

```js
type BLOGPOSTS = Entities<BLOGPOST>;
type PRODUCTS = Entities<PRODUCT>;
```

In order to convert them in type-safe manner into an array you can use the `Object.values` method provided by the JavaScript API - for more information please see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

It's possible to replace the method `buildArrayFromObject` by something like this:

```js
const isNil = <T>(a: T | null | undefined): a is null | undefined => a === null || a === undefined;
const isAssigned = <T>(a: T | null | undefined): a is T => !isNil(a);
const entitiesToArray = <T>(entity: Entities<T>): T[] => Object.values(entity).filter(isAssigned);
```

This method uses the `Object.values` method to convert the object into an array. Afterwards it get's filtered to contain an array without undefined values. Therefore I made use of two helper methods `isAssigned` and `isNil`. Please see this CodeSandbox for an example: [Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-elgamal-7detl?file=/index.ts)

Based on your concern, that the Object.value method is not supported by IE11, you can add a polyfill for that one. Either by pasting a polyfill in or by adding it using npm to your project.
Alternatively you can replace this code by the following answer [Use Object.keys to mimick Object.values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966443/3977134)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm looking for a simpler way to solve this. What if I decide that I'll only be using this function with these two object types: `BLOGPOSTS_ALL` and `PRODUCTS_ALL`. So I don't have to make the function "too" generic. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Actually there is. You can, if it's no problem for you, cast the return value of `Object.keys` in your solution like this: `const keys = Object.keys(obj) as K[];` then the issue magically disappears and my answer would then be a nice addendum. Let me know if it helped