# How to put the object properties as the table header?

Tags: angular

I have one  table,In which i want to put the table header name dynamically.

**component.html**

```
   `   <table class="table">
       <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr  *ngFor="let speak of speaker">
     <td>{{speak.name}}</td>
     <td>{{speak.matter}}</td>
     <td>{{speak.session}}</td>
     <td>{{speak.link}}</td>
     <td>{{speak.image}}</td>
     <td><button> Save</button>
         <button> Edit</button></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
      </table>`
```

I want to generate the table header as the propery name of object "speaker".How can i do?

Comment: Since your table values in the `td`s are "hard coded", there is not really a need to make the headers dynamic, is it?

Comment: @FredrikLundin I have to display different tables with this table template.So i wanna make it as a dynamic table.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the keys of the property you are using as model.

Have a method like this:

```
getKeys() {
  return (this.speakers && this.speakers.length > 0) ?  Object.keys(this.speakers[0]) : [];
}
```

And something like this in your template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let key of getKeys()">{{ key }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let speak of speakers">
        <td *ngFor="let key of getKeys()">{{ speak[key] }}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CQfTzZKedBEhgY3f5esf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a dynamic table header, just store the column names somewhere (for example a `columns` array) and do something like this

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{column}}</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

Keep in mind you may need to add empty columns in your header for your button columns. In the example above:

```
columns = ['name','matter','session','link','image','']
```

The last entry is the header for the buttons column.

Comment: Any option to take it directly from the  speaker

Comment: That's more complicated, you would need to enumerate the properties of the object. Also, suppose you have an empty collection to display on the table, you would not have an example object to build the header.

Comment: If you want to do that check this question on how to [enumerate properties on TypeScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201970/enumerate-properties-on-typescript-object). Also, consider editing your question as it is not clear it was that you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Store header names in an array and do ng-reapeat on that array.

$scope.headernames = ['name','matter','session','link','image'];

In HTML:

```
  <thead>
     <tr ng-repeat="names in headernames">
      <th>{{names}}</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: This solution is the angularjs way to do it, but OP is asking for angular (aka angular2/4). Yeah, what they did with the naming is quite confusing, and I always double check when I see the tag in a question.